# Why did the Doctor reveal this spoiler to Grant?

Tags: doctor-who

In the beginning of *The Return of Doctor Mysterio*, the Doctor reveals to a young Grant that

> Superman and Clark Kent are the same person.

What was the Doctor's goal? What did he hope to achieve?

Of course Grant already knew, but that's neither here nor there. The Doctor wasn't aware of that. So why did he say it?

Comment: It’s possible that he doesn’t actually know who they are, but given his other pop culture knowledge, I doubt it. He was probably just being funny (or being what he considered funny).

Comment: The Doctor just [forgot](http://textsfromsuperheroes.com/post/48640121368).

Answer (score 14):

The Doctor, having not encountered the Superman comics beforehand and only seeing a single example, was expecting that he'd discovered an enormous secret, one that he **couldn't help but share** and that would **demonstrate his cleverness to the small child he'd just met**. Note his disappointment when the child told him that ...

> *everyone knows that*

... which then led to him **showing off** some more on the roof, precipitating the events of the episode and **introducing the idea of a comic-book style hero with a pathetically simple disguise that any fool can see through**.

Comment: That was my initial interpretation, but given the Doctor’s previously demonstrated pop culture knowledge, I’d say he was just being the Doctor.

Comment: @Adamant - His visible disappointment suggested that he hasn't read the comics before. Failing that, he may simply have been trying to distract the boy/have fun at his expense/amuse himself/test him in some way. Really it's not clear what the Doctor knows/remembers after 1500+ years, much of which has been spent off-world.

Comment: I lean toward the “amuse himself” theory. He’s mentioned many pop-culture details both well-known and obscure in the past, so his having missed Superman would have been strange. But it is possible that he just never got around to reading a Superman comic or watching a Superman movie.

Comment: @Adamant - A very quick search suggests that his tastes lean more toward high culture (multiple references to poetry, opera, orchestras) rather than pop-culture. We do know that he's read [at least one comic](http://www.chakoteya.net/doctorwho/24-3.htm) but it's very outdated.

Comment: I think I'll have to watch it again. Not now though; at work. Later. In the meantime, have an upvote.

Comment: He was also surprised to learn that we had movies like "Alien" which were horror movies. "No wonder the aliens dislike you"

Comment: Not to mention his thinking that Wally (AKA Waldo in the USA) was in EVERY book.  In both cases he's saying it to / around children - both might just be an example of trying to be funny, or that he is indeed a madman with a box.

Answer (score 3):

Because he'd just figured it out, and wanted to share this amazing information with another fan of the series. That's what fans do. Theorise and share. Indeed, that's the entire purpose of this very site!

The joke in the scene is that Grant, like everyone else, already knew.